# Ruby code in idiomatic python

Tags: python, ruby

I'm practicing python, and I am having trouble converting my Ruby code to idiomatic python.

I'm able to query for a card, but I don't understand how to in one line (or succinctly as possible), query, filter and return a card from a query. My code is turning into a blob of try/except statements, so I'm guessing I am missing something.

**RUBY VERSION**

```
  #fetch the customer 
  customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(self.stripe_id)
  #Retrieve the card fingerprint using the stripe_card_token  
  card_fingerprint = Stripe::Token.retrieve(token_id).try(:card).try(:fingerprint) 
  # check whether a card with that fingerprint already exists
  default_card = customer.sources.all(:object => "card").select{|card| card.fingerprint ==  card_fingerprint}.last if card_fingerprint 
  #create new card if do not already exists
  default_card = customer.sources.create(:source => token_id) unless default_card 
  #set the default card of the customer to be this card, as this is the last card provided by User and probably he want this card to be used for further transactions
  customer.default_card = default_card.id 
  # save the customer
  customer.save
```

**PYTHON VERSION**

```
    # fetch the customer
    customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(self.stripe_id)
    # Blank default card, which will equal either an existing card or a new card
    default_card
    # Retrieve the card fingerprint using the stripe_card_token
    card_fingerprint = stripe.Token.retrieve(token_id)
    if card_fingerprint:
        # Return all customer cards
        default_cards = customer.sources.all(object='card')
        for card in default_cards
            if card.fingerprint == card_fingerprint:
                # Set default card to the matching card
                default_card = card
    # If not card found, create a new one
    if !default_card:
        customer.sources.create(source=token_id)
    # Set this card as default, regardless if it was new or exising
    customer.default_source = default_card.id
```

https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#retrieve_card

Comment: Why is it important to do this in a single line?  Your python code is only the first bit, but so far seems reasonable

Comment: Its not, I just thought there may be a more expressive way of doing this than a bunch of try except blocks. Otherwise It will turn into some for loop. I'll keep trying in the meantime

Comment: Can you add a sample of that try-catch blob code to your question?  I think I see what you're getting at, but it would help to see what you have

Comment: You probably want a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: @CodeGnome yes !!!! Thank you !

Comment: @CodeGnome can I define a query i.e. 'customer.sources.all(object='card')' within a list comprehension or does it need to be defined first ?

Comment: The link below should give you some options to your question along with more useful tips (at least it was for me, given I just moved from ruby to python)... 

(~10min read)
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/

Comment: @user3087106 thanks, would you mind checking below and telling me which is typically more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I've come up with ! I avoided the one-line if statements that I used in ruby, which was advised by the Python style guide, but looks strange to me coming from Ruby

**PYTHON VERSION**

```
    # Fetch the customer
    customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(self.stripe_id)
    # Retrieve the card fingerprint using the stripe_card_token
    card_fingerprint = stripe.Token.retrieve(token_id)
    if card_fingerprint:
        cards = [x for x in customer.sources.all(object='card') if x.fingerprint == card_fingerprint]
    # If a card or multiple cards return with said fingerprint, return the last one and assign default_card to this card
    if cards:
        default_card = cards.pop()
    # If no cards matched, create a new default card
    else:
        default_card = customer.sources.create(source=token_id)
    # Set this card as default, regardless if it was new or already existed
    customer.default_source = default_card.id
    customer.save()
    return customer.sources.all(object='card')
```

I could also replace the if else with a try except, and get rid of the local variable `cards` but not sure if this is idiomatic

```
        try:
            default_card = [x for x in customer.sources.all(object='card') if x.fingerprint == card_fingerprint].pop()
        except IndexError e:
            default_card = customer.sources.create(source=token_id)
```